# Aurora MySQL general_log not logging queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to log each query my Aurora MySQL is performing. In my custom Parameter group, correctly assigned to the Aurora instance, I edited the following params:

```
general_log: 1
```

Once I browse the instance page, I can successfully see the "general/mysql-general.log" entry in the log section but it does not contains any query (even for old rotated log files)

```
/rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.10 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time Id Command Argument
/rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.10 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time Id Command Argument
/rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.10 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time Id Command Argument
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

I can see from the metrics the DB is working with an average of 50/100 queries per second.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: After more investigation I noticed the "log_output" was set to "TABLE". Setting it to "FILE" solved the issue